# Using a library with a higher minSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

My app has a minSdkVersion of 8. I would like to use a library with a minSdkVersion of 14 on devices that support it and fallback to a different component if not. Theoretically, this might be possible using the new [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger), but it looks like there's a special case for minSdkVersion:

```
Defaults to 1.
The higher priority document's version will be used but importing a library with a more recent version will generate an error.
```

Is there a way to force gradle to include the library dependency so that I can deal with the SDK version issues?

Comment: I think there's a `<tools:node="replace">` recipe for this, but I don't have the details off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare's suggestion, I found the proper incantation. Everything works fine if I add this line to the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />
```